# Необходимо написать программу, которая считает количество циклов в перестановке

Tags: java

Перестановка осуществляется следующим образом. Как посчитать количество циклов в ней?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
      int swap = array[index];
      array[index] = array[i];
      array[i] = swap;
    }
```

Comment: Каких циклов? Сколько раз будет выполняться цикл for?

Comment: Нет, циклов в перестановке

Answer (score 1):

После тасования в массиве, представляющим собой перестановку чисел 1..n, может быть несколько циклов (disjoint cycles)

Для обнаружения циклов можно сделать следующее:

Cканировать массив слева направо, пока не встретим ненулевой элемент

Запомним его позицию `start`, положим `k=start`

Будем переходить на позицию `A[k] - 1`, пока `k` снова не станет равно `start` - цикл завершён

По пути будем обнулять все элементы (пометка пройденных)

Продолжим сканировать, начиная с позиции `start+1`, пока не найдём ненулевой элемент, и снова пойдём по циклу

```
[3, 1, 2, 4] 
start = 0 
k = 0
k = A[0] - 1 = 3-1 = 2; A[0] = 0
k = A[2] - 1 = 2-1 = 1; A[2] = 0
k = A[1] - 1 = 1-1 = 0 - вернулись к началу цикла; A[1]= 0
первый цикл обнаружен, содержит три элемента, они помечены.

[0, 0, 0, 4] находим start=3, указывает на себя же, 
второй цикл из одного элемента
```

Comment: @Alex Получилось реализовать?

Comment: к сожалению, нет

Comment: А в чём трудность?

Comment: не понятно почему этот алгоритм работает с математической точки зрения

Comment: Хм.. А что такое цикл? Это последовательность, хвост которой указывает на начало. Вот это свойство и используется.